# Calling GDALOpen from a function

Tags: gdal, c++

I'm trying to call `GDALOpen` from a function to open a tiff raster and then use the dataset further in my `main` or other functions.
This is the code I have so far:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
GDALAllRegister();
GDALDataset *poRasterDataset;
openRaster(poRasterDataset, argv[1]);
...}

void openRaster(GDALDataset * poDataset, char* rasterName){
poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen(rasterName, GA_ReadOnly);
...
}
```

My problem is if I do it this way my program crashes because it finds the `poRasterDataset` to be empty in `main` after calling `openRaster`, but if I call `GDALOpen` from `main` I have no problem using the dataset. I'm not very experienced in C++ but I suppose it has to do with how I'm passing `poDataset` in `main` after calling `openRaster`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you, it's from working code:

```
char* Raster = new char[FullPathMax];
wcstombs(Raster,argv[2],FullPathMax);
GDALAllRegister();
GDALDataset* SourceRasterDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen(Raster,GA_ReadOnly);
```

So there's nothing wrong with your implementation per se. The problem with your code is that in your code block:

```
GDALDataset *poRasterDataset;
openRaster(poRasterDataset, argv[1]);
```

C++ wont let you assign pointers inside a function, you don't actually pass *the pointer* but pass *the pointers' value*, have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416162/assignment-inside-function-that-is-passed-as-pointer for more info. Consider:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
GDALAllRegister();
GDALDataset *poRasterDataset = openRaster(argv[1]);
...}

GDALDataset* openRaster(char* rasterName){
GDALDataset poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen(rasterName, GA_ReadOnly);
return poDataset;
}
```

As an alternative. Also, be aware that `argv[1]` isn't necessarily a `char*`, it could be a `_TCHAR*` which doesn't work with GDALOpen, hence I've used [wcstombs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wcstombs/) (safer version [wcstombs_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/wcstombs)) to convert the `_TCHAR` pointer to `char`(byte) pointer.